# Unable to update plug-ins - Undefined index a:1:{s:3:"ssl";b:1;} in class-requests.php on line 213

Tags: php, 500-internal-error, configuration, iis

After our hosting provider moved our site to a new Windows 2016 server I have been struggling with an intermittent error:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: a:1:{s:3:"ssl";b:1;} in E:\WebContent\site-name\wp-includes\class-requests.php on line 213

We see this occasionally on the login screen.  A refresh of the browser will usually fix it. The rest of the site seems to be running fine.

This happens EVERY TIME when I try to update plug-ins or WordPress. Based on reading many posts, it seems to be an issue with TLS.  It is true the TLS 1.0 is not available on the new server.  TLS1.0 was deprecated due to security issues. It's been replaced by TLS1.2.  But I can't seem to find any suggestions for how to fix this error.  I'm sure it's a configuration error with the server or with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error gone after I enabled the openssl in php.ini.

Uncommented folloging line, changed from: **;extension=openssl** 
to **extension=openssl**